# NSUserDefaults Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

If I set an NSUserDefault in one file(playerdata.m) could I access that value from another file(calculator.m)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, so long as both are running under the same instance of NSApplication (meaning both files exist within the same program).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. NSUserDefaults are available to your app and accessed by the `standUserDefaults` object. Check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: But when I try to use it in another file xcode says my prefs are undeclared. Do I need to redefine my NSUserDefault ?

Comment: You already marked this answered. So you should have your answer.